# Hadoop Streaming program subprocess failed with code 139

Tags: python, hadoop, memory-leaks, multiprocessing, emr

I'm running a Hadoop streaming program (written in Python) over Amazon EMR that is having some issues. It all runs fine when I do tests with a few thousand records and I've tested the program locally a ton of times, all seems to go well. But when I increase to a full dataset (~8GB of URLs that I need to request) I get the following:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 139
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:372)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:586)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.map(PipeMapper.java:125)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:441)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:377)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 139
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:372)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:586)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:441)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:377)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

Reviewing the userlogs and stderr, I see nothing strange about how my program is running, I have a good bit of debug logging going on in my Python program, and everything seems good within the Python program. I should mention that the program is a Python multiprocessing HTTP request program  and possibly related: reviewing the stats for the machine over time the memory usage seems to increase indefinitely.

Here is my Hadoop configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
  <property><name>mapred.output.committer.class</name><value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.DirectFileOutputCommitter</value></property>
  <property><name>mapred.reduce.tasks.speculative.execution</name><value>true</value></property>
  <property><name>mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum</name><value>2</value></property>
  <property><name>mapred.task.tracker.http.address</name><value>0.0.0.0:9103</value></property>
  <property><name>mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution</name><value>true</value></property>
  <property><name>mapred.userlog.retain.hours</name><value>48</value></property>
  <property><name>mapred.job.reuse.jvm.num.tasks</name><value>20</value></property>
  <property><name>io.sort.factor</name><value>48</value></property>
  <property><name>mapred.reduce.parallel.copies</name><value>20</value></property>
  <property><name>mapred.reduce.tasks</name><value>84</value></property>
  <property><name>tasktracker.http.threads</name><value>20</value></property>
  <property><name>hadoop.job.history.user.location</name><value>none</value></property>
  <property><name>mapred.job.tracker.handler.count</name><value>64</value></property>
  <property><name>mapred.map.output.compression.codec</name><value>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec</value></property>
  <property><name>mapred.output.direct.NativeS3FileSystem</name><value>true</value></property>
  <property><name>mapred.reduce.tasksperslot</name><value>1.75</value></property>
  <property><name>mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum</name><value>1</value></property>
  <property><name>mapred.compress.map.output</name><value>true</value></property>
  <property><name>mapred.output.compression.codec</name><value>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec</value></property>
  <property><name>mapred.job.tracker.http.address</name><value>0.0.0.0:9100</value></property>
  <property><name>mapred.local.dir</name><value>/mnt/var/lib/hadoop/mapred</value></property>
  <property><name>mapred.job.tracker</name><value>172.31.7.89:9001</value></property>
  <property><name>io.sort.mb</name><value>200</value></property>
  <property><name>mapred.map.tasks</name><value>7000</value></property>
  <property><name>mapred.max.map.failures.percent</name><value>10</value></property>
</configuration>
```

I'm not quite sure where to start debugging this one, I read that exit status 139 is basically a segfault. I'm not doing any low level memory manipulation, so this is surprising. Any ideas on where to start here? Could this be a memory leak in my Python program? Any other logs I can look at? Any Hadoop config values that I missed?

Answer (score 4):

`ErrNo 139` means that Hadoop decided that your script got stuck because it didn't make any output for a long time.

Be sure that you map subroutine provides output often enough,

or you can tune Hadoop and set timeout for map output.